# jquery find image class in div

Tags: jquery, image, class

Jquery question here.

I would like to get the CLASS tag of the only image that sits inside `<div id=slot></div>`

How can I do this? Can't seem to find anything on google.

Comment: Be sincere, for how long have you Googled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$('#slot img').attr('class')
```

[**DEMO**](http://%24%28%27#slot%20img%27%29.attr%28%27class%27%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#slot img:first').attr('class');
```

or

```
$('#slot img:eq(0)').attr('class');
```

or

```
$('#slot img').eq(0).attr('class');
```

or

```
$('#slot img').first().attr('class');
```

If `#slot` contain only one image then

```
$('#slot img').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var classNames = $("#slot img:first").attr("class");
```

You'll get whatever is in that class attribute. If there are many classes in there it will return all of them, if there is only one you'll get just that.

This selector says give me the first image that is within the element with the ID of slot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourClass=$("#slot").find("img:first").attr("class");
alert(yourClass);
```

jsfiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/3c4yK/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgClasss=$('#slot img:first').prop('class');
```

Or

```
var imgClasss=$('#slot img:first').attr('class');
```